# Regex: Is the string starting with capital letter (not only in A-Z)?

Tags: php, regex

How can I check if a string starts with a capital letter, in cases where the first letter might not be in A-Z range but from other languages also AND simultaneously if the first character is not a number?

examples:

```
"This is string" - match
"this is string" - not match
"5 not good" - not match
"Увеличи starts capital" - match
"мащабиране no capital" - not match
```

in php:

```
if (preg_math('/??/i', $str) ) {
  echo 'yeeee haaa';
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [this documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) and the property `Lu`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
preg_match('#^\p{Lu}#u', $str)
```

`\p{Lu}` will match any character that has Unicode character property of uppercase letter.

[**Demo on regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/pR1mS4/3) (please ignore the flags `m` and `g`, they are for demonstration purpose only)

When you are dealing with a Unicode string (or more specifically, in the case of `preg_` functions, the Unicode string must be in UTF-8 encoding), **you must always use the `u` flag** to make the engine treat the input string and the pattern with character semantics. Otherwise, by default, `preg_` functions treat the pattern and input string as an array of bytes and produce an unexpected result for characters outside the ASCII range.

Comment: best answer - (this still not match my 4th example - but noo problem)

Comment: @faq: It should match, though. The demo shows that it matches (note that the demo site is using PHP's regex)

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
if ($string{0} != mb_strtoupper($string{0}, 'UTF-8')) {
    // not uppercase
}
```

Comment: This will include characters that don't have case. I don't know whether those are wanted or not, though.

Comment: yes, that's true. It was only an idea how it could work without regex.

Comment: @faq: You should try it first. For numbers, since the upper case of a number is the same as itself, it will return true.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
if (strtoupper($str[0]) == $str[0])
{
   echo "match";
}
```

or:

```
if(ctype_upper($str[0]))
{
   echo "match";
}
```

I'm not sure they would work with every character set.

Comment: Both solutions are locale dependent. They will not work if the character is outside the current locale.